# how to mock constructor in sub third party attribute using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, winston

We have a simple express app. We use winston as third party to be able to handle logging properly.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { createLogger, transports } = require('winston');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const logger = createLogger({ transports: [ new transports.Console()] });

const { catchAll } = require('./routes/catchall');

app.get('*', catchAll);

app.listen(port, () => logger.log({ level: 'info', message: `server listening on port ${port}!` }));
```

We would like, in our unit testing, check that createLogger has been called with proper arguments.

We first tried just to use `jest.mock('winston)` but jest complains that `TypeError: transports.Console is not a constructor`.

We then tried to mock manually the package using:

```
let { createLogger, transports } = require('winston');

const consoleClass = class Console{};
jest.doMock('winston', () => {
  return {
    createLogger: jest.fn(),
    transports: {
      Console: consoleClass
    }
  }
});

describe('logger', () => {
  it('should create proper logger', () => {
    expect(createLogger).lastCalledWith({ transports: [ new transports.Console()] })
  });
});
```

The error about Console is gone. But then our test fails with:

```
logger › should create proper logger

expect(jest.fn())[.not].lastCalledWith()

jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received:
  function: [Function anonymous]

  39 | describe('logger', () => {
  40 |   it('should create proper logger', () => {
> 41 |     expect(createLogger).lastCalledWith({ transports: [ new transports.Console()] })
     |                          ^
  42 |   });
  43 | });
  44 |

  at Object.lastCalledWith (tests/app.spec.js:41:26)
```

We tried to add after `doMock`

```
createLogger.mockImplementation(() => {});
```

But it complained that `TypeError: createLogger.mockImplementation is not a function`

How can we both replace transports attribute and createLogger?

We need to be able to mock implementation of `createLogger` to then be able in another test to assert that `app.listen` has been called with logger.log and proper parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the following one:

```
const mockCreateLogger = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  log: jest.fn()
});
const mockConsole = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => () => {});
jest.mock('winston', () => ({
  createLogger: mockCreateLogger, // name must start with mock prefix
  transports: {
    Console: mockConsole // name must start with mock prefix
  }
}));

// here import the file you are testing after the mocks

describe('logger', () => {
  it('should create proper logger', () => {
    expect(mockCreateLogger).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ transports: expect.anything() })
  });
});
```

p.s. for writing properly your unit tests here, you should mock also `express` in order to work on the mocked `app` rather than importing the "real" express

Comment: Your code returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Console' of undefined`. Transports is not a method it's an attribute, so I guess `mockTransports = jest.fn().mockImplementation` cannot be done this way.

Express is already mocked I simplified the test to only show relevant part for logger :)

Comment: It complains again TypeError: Cannot read property 'Console' of undefined
       7 | const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    >  8 | const logger = createLogger({ transports: [ new transports.Console()] });

Comment: did you add the brackets as are in the snippet? `new mockTransports()`

Comment: yes. The complain is quoting my logger in my app file, not the test file :) Because changing transprt to be a function doesn't replace the need for the script to expect an attribute in real life... `const logger = createLogger({ transports: [ new transports.Console()] });`

Comment: oh actually yep, sorry my bad. I 've changed the snippet, try with the updated one for now and let's see if the issue has been bypassed, then we will change the `anything()` with the right instance

Comment: `TypeError: transports.Console is not a constructor` it's a nightmare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187131/discussion-between-quirimmo-and-blackholegalaxy).